# Five steps method not working after one step

Tags: javascript, events, button

So I'm trying to code the 54321 method to ground anxiety, however the method works for the first step, which means a button disappears and the text changes but after that the button disappears one by one as they should but the text doesn't change.

At first the method worked when I had an onclick event in html linked to a function in my js file. Now I want to remove the onclick event and replace it by `'click .thebtn'(event, instance) {}` in the js file but the method doesn't work anymore.

The methods is supposed to go on like this. When the five buttons are clicked, one disappears and the text changes, then when the four buttons are clicked, one disappears and the text changes and so on until there's no button left.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id= "step1">Identify 5 things you see</div>
    <button class= "thebtn" id="button1">Button1</button>
    <button class= "thebtn" id="button2">Button2</button>
    <button class= "thebtn" id="button3">Button3</button>
    <button class= "thebtn" id="button4">Button4</button>
    <button class= "thebtn" id="button5">Button5</button>
</div>

<script>
Template.theMethod.events({
    'click .thebtn'(event, instance) {
        compteur ++;
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.currentTarget.setAttribute('class', 'thebtn2');
        // // Update state on button click
        answered[event.currentTarget.id] = true;
        var allTrue = Object.keys(answered).every(function(key){ return answered[key] });
        if (allTrue) {
            // // Remove a button and reset state
            document.getElementById("button" + numberOfButtons).style.display = "none";
            if (compteur == 5) {
                document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML = "Identify 4 things you see"; 
            //document.getElementsByClassName("thebtn2").setAttribute('class', 'thebtn');
            } else if (compteur == 9){
                document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML = "Identify 3 things you see";   
            } else if (compteur ==9){
                document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML = "Identify 2 things you see";
            } else if (compteur ==15){
                document.getElementById("step1").innerHTML = "Identify 1 things you see";
            }
        }
    }
});    
</script>
```

Comment: We probably have to see how `Template.theMethod.events()` is coded. Also, the `if (compteur == x)` logic seems weird since the number that has to be written in the step1 innerHTML is equal to the number of buttons used - the step the user is in, so it can be one line of code.

Comment: @Shilly The Template is the html I posted before the script. And I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about the compteur logic.

Comment: yes, but `Template.theMethod.events()` is not native javascript. So without the name of the library you use, I have no idea which docs to consult. Anyways, after playing around with the code a bit, the issues I see is 1) when is `numberOfButtons` increased? Since without it, only button1 is ever disappearing. 2) When do you reset answers back to all false? Else starting the second round when you only have to click 4 things immediately tries removing the button again since every value inside answered is still true.

Comment: I have deleted my working answer fixing the two points in my previous comment, since people downvote it without any comment. But that is where your issue it. Reset state and numberOfButtons appropriately.

Comment: @Shilly Would you consider reposting it again ? I didn't see it

Comment: @Shilly, that's ok I just solved the problem. Thank you for your advice !